# how to preserve the extent of a spatial object (e.g. SpatialPoints) after "over()"

Tags: spatial, overlap, r-sp

For example, I have two SpatialPoints objects (a, and b). After I use the "over" function:
c<-a[b,]
the extent of c might have a different extent. Is there a way that while doing the selecting, the extent of a (or b) can be preserved?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
a[b,,drop=FALSE]
```

it should leave the bounding box of `a` in tact.